# Match whole word

Tags: python, django

I want to search the input that user fill in the web.

I called input as `aranan`, but it dose not work properly.

I search `urla` but it return me `memurlarin` . the `urla` is inside the word `memurlarin`. but I want to get back just sentences that `urla` is in it.

```
if form.is_valid():
    cd = form.cleaned_data
    aranan = cd['aranan']

    sen1 = pd.read_csv('.../Corpus.csv',encoding="utf-8") 
    sen1 = sen1.sentence1_stop  

    sen2 = pd.read_csv(.../Corpus.csv',encoding="utf-8") 
    sen2 = sen2.sentence2_stop 

    for i in range(len(sen1)):
        if (aranan in sen1[i] and  aranan in sen2[i]):
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line I guess:

```
for i in range(len(sen1)):
    if (aranan in sen1[i] and  aranan in sen2[i]):
```

You can't iterate over the words of your sentences in this way because they may have different length and you won't be able to test all of their words. And this is not the efficient way either. If you just want to test if the word is in the sentence and return the sentence then you can make it in this way:

```
results = [sent for sent in [sent1, sent2] if aranan in sent]
```

Here `results` list will contain the sentences which have the `aranan` in them.